# A sum with harmonic number

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

i trying to evaluate this and i made some results , so could any one try this:

$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{{\rm H}_{k}}{n+1-k}) $.

Comment: You mein like a closed formula? What is your result?

Comment: Is there a reason to suspect that there is a closed form expression for this sum?

Comment: at least a formula involving only ${\rm H}_{n}$ and/or 'n'